# <body> element not at the top of the page

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, google-chrome, scrollto

Over at my site, I have noticed that while the `scrollTo()` method in jQuery functions fine in Firefox, it does not go to the top in Chrome.

I think that has something to do with the fact that my `<body>` tag seems to start away from top of the page, but I have failed to find the CSS that is at fault!

Is this a known issue or have I made a mistake?

http://mildfuzz.com

Comment: The WebKit browsers don't really like doing scrolling via the body element.  You might see if things work better if you wrap the body content in a `<div>` that's given no padding, no margin, and 100% height and width. ([I asked kind-of the same question a long time ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830080/jquery-scrolltop-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-safari-or-chrome-windows).)

Comment: Post code instead of a link to your site.  Once you fix a problem on a site you've linked to the question becomes pointless without code.

Comment: Closed as not a real question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$('body, html')` instead of just `$('body')`