# Chrome vs Firefox vs IE - Scrolling Issue

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, browser

I am developing a site and it seems to behave differently when in Chrome. Scrolling is not consistent or smooth. It keeps on stopping. However, when I load the same site in Firefox or IE9, I have no problems. Everything scrolls smoothly.

++++++++EDIT++++++++
I was able to fix my problem by adding the following meta tag to my template:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

I am not sure why, but it seems to fix it... as well as other problems I was having

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem in Chrome and the solution is not logically clear to me.Something to do with how chrome is rendering the javascript. However, on adding a parent container div to the scrolling content it seems to work fine. There is a solution to this problem in javascript in the following link with an example

[Stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830080/jquery-scrolltop-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-safari-or-chrome-windows)

For the link you have added to your web page it is more to do with IE than chrome. Do you have chrome frame installed in IE ?

I do not know the technology you are using but the below code will give a hint to the solution.In Gwt (Google web toolkit) I worked out the solution as follows:

My earlier code which was causing the issue was as follows

Old Code:

```
        <g:FocusPanel addStyleNames="{style.scrollable} {style.fullHeight}" ui:field="bodyContainer">
        <b:CellTable width="100%" ui:field="bodyTable"/>
        </g:FocusPanel>
```

New Code: 
      CSS :

```
     #scrollContainer {
       overflow:auto;
       position:absolute;
       top:0px; height:100%; width:100%;
     }

 HTML:
    <div id="scrollContainer">
    <g:FocusPanel ui:field="bodyContainer">
        <b:CellTable width="100%" ui:field="bodyTable"/>
    </g:FocusPanel>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps!