# jQuery - margin-top not updating in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I'm trying to animate some IMG elements by updating the top margin with some simple maths.

It goes like this:

```
$('.spd2').css('margin-top', - offsetPC * 12 + '%');
```

It is applyed to IMGs like this:

```
<img src="img/pgDadosImportantes_i001.png" class="spd1" 
    style="right: 30%; top: 45%; z-index:10;" />
```

With this style set in css doc:

```
.ilustras {
    width: 960px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}

.ilustras img {
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    width: auto; 
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

It works in Firefox and IE very well. The problem is that in chrome, the value of margin-top is not  being updated.

I tried several changes to all involved elements, changing attributes as position, float, width, height, display... and chaned some ways of naming marginLeft, margin-left in jQuery.

Nothing is working with Chrome. If I apply a static number it works.

I have a sample here:

http://unitfour.com.br/HotsiteCluster/

Apreciate any help!!

*sorry about my english and my code... I'm a Brazilian Designer working out both!

Comment: $('.spd1').css('margin-top', - offsetPC * 12 + '%'); you should write this in your jquery script, as in img tag you have given class="spd1"

Comment: Didn't get the point.. but thax for answer.

Comment: Debugging the offsetPC var, Google Chrome is the only one that returns "infinity".

Comment: @FabioMontone: Can you tell us where offsetPC is set and what value it has?

Comment: @TJ. It was set and the value was variable depending on the percentage of the page scroll. But It was not showing in Webkit (Chrome / Safari) because - in a strange fashion - they don't get scrollTop(); values. I've solved the problem using **bold**window.pageYOffset**bold** to compose my vars. Hope that help other people! Thank you all for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not showing in Webkit (Chrome / Safari) because - in a strange fashion - they don't get `scrollTop();` values. I've solved the problem using `window.pageYOffset` to compose my vars. Hope that help other people! Thank you all for helping!

Comment: Adding to your solution, this post may help to explain why scrollTop does not work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830080/jquery-scrolltop-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-safari-or-chrome-windows

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
$('.spd2').css('margin-top', ((parseInt($('.spd2').css('margin-top')) - offsetPC) * 12) + '%');
```

And tell us if it is OK.