# jquery remove class not working in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, addclass, scrolltop, removeclass

this code is working in Firefox but not in Chrome v.23.
When I trace the code in debugger everything works fine but **Chrome doesn't change class**. Any ideas?

```
$(document).scroll(function () {

    $('a.nav').each(function () {

        var divTop = $('#' + this.title).offset().top;
        var distance = divTop - $("html").scrollTop();
        if (distance > 210 && distance < 255) {

            $('a.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: But addClass() and removeClass() work fine for me in chrome

Comment: can you recreate the problem and share the code at http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Yikes that code is going to be a performance problem. You should probably look at throttling the scroll. And if you finds a match for active, you should exit out of the each loop. And you should not keep looking up the html's scrolltop, do that outside the each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is targeting $("html") for scrolltop.

See this SO thread: [jQuery scrollTop() doesn't seem to work in Safari or Chrome (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830080/jquery-scrolltop-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-safari-or-chrome-windows)

See the second answer for details on what's actually going on with your scenario, i.e. try using $('body')

Either of the first two solutions should work for you, though.

Comment: THANK YOU!
replaced the $("html") with $("body,html,document") and works fine in Firefox and Chrome.