# Adding jQuery .scrollTop to if statement

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

Does anyone know how add to this script?

I need to check whether the visitor is at the top of the page? If not call the fallback script.

E.g. if user is at top of page delay animation, if user is elsewhere remove delay (fallback else condition).

```
var viewportWidth = $(window).width(),
    stopTabletAnimation = 1024,
    scrTop;

$(window).on("load scroll", function() {
    scrTop = $("html, body").scrollTop();
    if (!scrTop && viewportWidth > stopTabletAnimation){
        // DELAY ANIMATION - FORCE TOP CORRECTLY (WITH A DELAY - .9s)
        $('.website-navigation').delay(3500).animate({top:0}, 900, function() {
            // Confirm Above if successful!
            console.log('ANIMATION COMPLETE: .site-head Delayed, then loaded!');
        });

    } else {
        // Do Not Animate
        $('.website-navigation').css({top: '0'});
        console.log('NO ANIMATION: Inforce Set Height');
    }
});
```

Comment: And... where have you used the scroll event? And what have you tried to get the scrollTop value?

Comment: I wanted to jQuery scrollTop, however combining it into the if condition above proved useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the check from

```
scrTop = $("html, body").scrollTop();
```

To

```
scrTop = $("body").scrollTop();
```

This will detect how far away from the top the user is.

Edit:
This should be set with

```
scrTop = $(window).scrollTop();
```

Ass explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2422159/1809751

Comment: Thanks for the add, its always in the finer detail!

Comment: @NeilLittle I might be missing something... but what's wrong with `$("html, body").scrollTop();` ?

Comment: $("html, body").scrollTop(); always returns 0 in Chrome. It may even be better to get value with $(window).scrollTop();

Comment: Made the additional edit. @Tom Burgess was right code seems smoother.

Answer (score 1):

```
var scrTop;

$(window).on("load scroll", function() {
  scrTop = $("html, body").scrollTop();
  if(!scrTop){ //if scrollTop is at 0

  }else{

  }
});
```

or in your case probably something like:

```
if (!scrTop && viewportWidth > stopTabletAnimation){
```

Comment: Just about to add my comment, 6 seconds to slow :) Let me update the code. And see what happens!

Comment: May I ask on your latest update what the difference between && and || is?

Comment: @Neil `&&` means that both `condition` **AND** `condition` must be truthy, while `||` means that just one `condition` **OR** `condition` need to be truthy to validate

Comment: I have made the amends, but to no avail. It seems to be trapped in the loop as it does not return the else statement. If I scroll down the page and reloaded the page I still get the incorrect console message and coded delay. Cache has been emptied.

Comment: Thanks for get the grunt of scrTop variable. Much appreciated!