# $(window).scrollTop() is not working in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

It works fine on firefox and chrome,but safari seem to have some issue.Here is the code.

```
function founders() {
var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollPos == 900) {
        $(function() {
            $(".first_fall").fadeIn(1000);
            $(".second_fall").fadeIn(2000);
            $(".third_fall").fadeIn(3000);
        });
    };
}
```

And this is how I have called it

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
            founders();
        });
   });
```

The very same function works well on safari and chrome on a different page.Here is the code

```
$(function() {
    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        zoomed();
    });
}());

function zoomed() {
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollPos >= 500 && scrollPos <= 800) {
            $(function() {
               $('#icon_you').animate({
                opacity: 0
            });

            $('.about_head').animate({
                opacity: 1
            });
        });
    } else {
        $(function() {
            $('.about_head').animate({
                opacity: 0
            });
            $('#icon_you').animate({
                opacity: 1
            });
        });
    };
    if (scrollPos >= 1100 && scrollPos <= 1500) {
        $(function() {
            $('.about_company_head').animate({
                opacity: 1
            });
            $('#icon_company').animate({
                opacity: 0
            });
        });
    } else {
        (function() {
            $('.about_company_head').animate({
                opacity: 0
            });
            $('#icon_company').animate({
                opacity: 1
            });
        });
    };
    if (scrollPos >= 1700 && scrollPos <= 2200) {
        $(function() {
            $('.about_project_head').animate({
                opacity: 1
            });
            $('#icon_project').animate({
                opacity: 0
            });
        });
    } else {
        $(function() {
            $('.about_project_head').animate({
                opacity: 0
            });
            $('#icon_project').animate({
                opacity: 1
            });
        });
    };
    if (scrollPos >= 2700 && scrollPos < 3200) {
        $(function() {
            $('.about_practical_head').animate({
                opacity: 1
            });
            $('#icon_practical').animate({
                opacity: 0
            });
        });
    } else {
        $(function() {
            $('.about_practical_head').animate({
                opacity: 0
            });
            $('#icon_practical').animate({
                opacity: 1
            });
        })
    };
}
```

Comment: What version of Safari are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sander.I use version 5.1.7

Comment: Will it make any difference if you use $(document).scrollTop() or does it give you the same result? Or maybe even $("html").scrollTop()?

Comment: Isn't the $(window).scrollTop() supposed to be more browser campatible than the others?Anyway let me try and get back to you in a moment.

Comment: Hey Sander,I tried both with no luck. $(""html).scrollTop() even broke chrome support and hence I reverted back to $(window).scrollTop() itself.

Comment: Ofcourse, I assume that you are using the desktop version of Safari and not Mobile Safari?

Comment: Yes, you guessed it right.And I am testing it on a PC,if that helps.

Comment: Please try and use the Web Inspector tool in Safari to evaluate what is returned when running $(window).scrollTop()

Comment: It returned me 0,but to my amusement the same $(window).scrollTop() used in another page is working fine.

Comment: Have you tried running a different version of jQuery on your site?

Comment: I have two jQuery files there.One the latest 1.11.1 version and another for jQuery knobs.All my other files are in a separate JS file which doesn't return any error and everything else is working fine too.

Comment: It seems this problem solved earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830080/jquery-scrolltop-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-safari-or-chrome-windows

Comment: Yeah.The answer there with most number of upvotes says that using $("body") should fix the issue and same was prescribed by Matt below.But in my case it is not working.Please not that this is just for safari.It works like a charm in chrome.I guess if the jQuery latest version has something to do here.Anyway I'll keep trying.If anything works out.I shall post back here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

`var scrollPos = $("body").scrollTop();`

webkit browsers always render window/html scrollTop as zero.

Comment: This is not solving the problem.But it works well in chrome.Sorry I had a typo earlier.But it works in chrome only.