# Smooth scrolling not working jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using the code from https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/ and for the likes of me can't figure out why it's not working.

Script:

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
    || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
       if (target.length) {
         $('html,body').animate({
             scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    }
}
});
```

Website:
[www.soelite.net/layout/](http://www.soelite.net/layout)

Any ideas what it could be? The site jumps to the div container but doesn't animate.

Comment: show us your HTML in your question as well, it's a better and quicker way to let us help you

Comment: Works fine for me. Where exactly is it not working? Pleas provide a workflow to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @jahller seems to be not working in safari.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2234749/606104

> I was having this problem in safari and chrome (Mac) and discovered that .scrollTop would work on $("body") but not $("html, body")

To make it work in Safari change your script to:

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
    || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');

    if (target.length) {
      var bodyElement = $("html,body");
      if ($.browser.safari) { 
        bodyElement = $("body")
      }

      bodyElement.animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
      }, 1000);

      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Attempted this, it stopped working completely in all browsers.