# Why body.scrollTop is not working on Google chrome and Firefox but working on Microsoft edge

Tags: javascript, html, css

Previously `body.scrollTop` was working in my chrome.....but suddenly `body.scrollTop` is returning 0 in firefox and chrome......but returning proper value in Microsoft edge..

can anyone help me out?

Comment: [This is an old problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830080/jquery-scrolltop-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-safari-or-chrome-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `document.documentElement.scrollTop` to return scroll position value

**Update:**
Use both

```
var value = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
```

Comment: Thanks... :) Working