# Why does ScrollTop position not work on mobile Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, scrolltop

I have a feature on my website where the logo scrolls vertically depending on the users position on the site.

You can see it working on Chrome [here](https://www.shereewalker.com)

However it does not work on Safari, which includes mobile and tablet.

The scroll position does not seem to change at all in the console.

```
// logo positioning  

let logos, logoHeight, barTopMargin;
let viewportHeight;

window.addEventListener('load', init);
window.addEventListener('resize', setSizes);
document.addEventListener('scroll', update);


function init(lockUpdate) {
    logos = document.querySelectorAll('.scroll-text');
    setSizes(lockUpdate);
}

function update() {
    // ensure initialization and prevent recursive call
    if (!logos) init(true);
    //*************************************************

    /**************************************************
        THIS LINE MUST BE HERE.
    **************************************************/
    let maxScrollDist  = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - viewportHeight;
    //*************************************************

    let currentScrollPos = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    let newTop;

    let middle = currentScrollPos + viewportHeight/2;
    let middleY = maxScrollDist/2;

    if (middle >= (maxScrollDist+viewportHeight)/2) {
        let p = (middleY - Math.floor(middle - (maxScrollDist+viewportHeight)/2))*100/middleY;

        newTop = viewportHeight/2 - logoHeight/2;
        newTop += (100-p)*(viewportHeight/2)/100;
        newTop -= (100-p)*(barTopMargin +logoHeight/2)/100;
        newTop = Math.max(newTop, viewportHeight/2 - logoHeight/2); /*fix*/
    } else {
        let p = (middleY - Math.floor(-middle + (maxScrollDist+viewportHeight)/2))*100/middleY;
        newTop = barTopMargin*(100-p)/100+(viewportHeight/2 - (logoHeight/2)*p/100 )*p/100;
        newTop = Math.min(newTop, viewportHeight/2 - logoHeight/2); /*fix*/
    }

    logos.forEach(function(el) {
        el.style.top = newTop + "px";
    });
}

function setSizes(lockUpdate) {
    logoHeight     = logos[0].offsetHeight;
    barTopMargin   = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#page'), '::before').top);
    viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
    if (lockUpdate === true) return;
    update();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830080/jquery-scrolltop-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-safari-or-chrome-windows

Comment: Have a look at some of these suggestions: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2512

Comment: Thanks Brett - I did actually look at this, but unfortunately I don't understand JS or the syntax enough to know HOW to apply this information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason behind this behavior is laid inside the difference in scrolling implementation between the browsers. For example Chrome calculates page scrolling based on the `<html>`, while Safari does the same on the `<body>`.

**Chrome:**

[image: chrome scrollingElement]

**Safari:**

[image: safari scrollingElement]

Considering this info it would reasonable to assume that in Safari `document.documentElement` is completely unaware of page global scrolling value.

And to fix this issue you could define a helper func that uses `document.scrollingElement` with fallback to `getBoundingClientRect` on `document.documentElement`:

```
function getScrollingElement() {
  if (document.scrollingElement) {
    return document.scrollingElement;
  }

  const docElement = document.documentElement;
  const docElementRect = docElement.getBoundingClientRect();

  return {
    scrollHeight: Math.ceil(docElementRect.height),
    scrollTop: Math.abs(docElementRect.top)
  }
}
```

and use it in your `update` func:

```
function update() {
  // ensure initialization and prevent recursive call
  if (!logos) init(true);
  //*************************************************

  /**************************************************
      THIS LINE MUST BE HERE.
  **************************************************/
  let maxScrollDist = getScrollingElement().scrollHeight - viewportHeight;
  //*************************************************

  let currentScrollPos = getScrollingElement().scrollTop;

  // ...
}

function getScrollingElement() {
  // ...
}
```

Full code:

```js
// logo positioning  

let logos, logoHeight, barTopMargin;
let viewportHeight;

window.addEventListener('load', init);
window.addEventListener('resize', setSizes);
document.addEventListener('scroll', update);


function init(lockUpdate) {
    logos = document.querySelectorAll('.scroll-text');
    setSizes(lockUpdate);
}

function update() {
    // ensure initialization and prevent recursive call
    if (!logos) init(true);
    //*************************************************

    /**************************************************
        THIS LINE MUST BE HERE.
    **************************************************/
    let maxScrollDist  = getScrollingElement().scrollHeight - viewportHeight;
    //*************************************************

    let currentScrollPos = getScrollingElement().scrollTop;
    let newTop;

    let middle = currentScrollPos + viewportHeight/2;
    let middleY = maxScrollDist/2;

    if (middle >= (maxScrollDist+viewportHeight)/2) {
        let p = (middleY - Math.floor(middle - (maxScrollDist+viewportHeight)/2))*100/middleY;

        newTop = viewportHeight/2 - logoHeight/2;
        newTop += (100-p)*(viewportHeight/2)/100;
        newTop -= (100-p)*(barTopMargin +logoHeight/2)/100;
        newTop = Math.max(newTop, viewportHeight/2 - logoHeight/2); /*fix*/
    } else {
        let p = (middleY - Math.floor(-middle + (maxScrollDist+viewportHeight)/2))*100/middleY;
        newTop = barTopMargin*(100-p)/100+(viewportHeight/2 - (logoHeight/2)*p/100 )*p/100;
        newTop = Math.min(newTop, viewportHeight/2 - logoHeight/2); /*fix*/
    }

    logos.forEach(function(el) {
        el.style.top = newTop + "px";
    });
}

function getScrollingElement() {
  if (document.scrollingElement) {
    return document.scrollingElement;
  }

  const docElement = document.documentElement;
  const docElementRect = docElement.getBoundingClientRect();

  return {
    scrollHeight: Math.ceil(docElementRect.height),
    scrollTop: Math.abs(docElementRect.top)
  }
}

function setSizes(lockUpdate) {
    logoHeight     = logos[0].offsetHeight;
    barTopMargin   = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#page'), '::before').top);
    viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
    if (lockUpdate === true) return;
    update();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi there - thank you very much for your time. I have tried inserting this both immediately after:

`let currentScrollPos = getScrollingElement().scrollTop;`

And in between the two sets of functions but it does not work. Sorry if it is obvious, but I don't understand where exactly to insert this in my current code. Thanks

Comment: just tested it out. works fine if you simply define `function getScrollingElement` right after your `function update`. updated an answer to be more clear

Comment: This works perfectly. I have awarded you the bounty - thank you very much!