# windows.scroll working in chrome but not in safari

Tags: javascript

I want to scroll the page to the top, I tried the following 2 methods which are working in Chrome but not in Safari.

```
//Method 1
$("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");

//Method 2
window.scroll({
 top: 0, 
 left: 0, 
 behavior: 'smooth' 
});
```

Comment: maybe some answers there ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/1830080/2143734

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `scrollTo`

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp

Lists browsersupport for Safari